# Certbot failing with: ssl.SSLError: [X509] no certificate or crl found (_ssl.c:3732)

Tags: certbot

This is a copy of a recent [Let's Encrypt community forum thread](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/ssl-sslerror-x509-no-certificate-or-crl-found-ssl-c-3732/127954) which helped me mitigate the issue. I am adding this here since it could potentially affect more users.

---

I have a server with currently three websites using Let's Encrypt. These certs get renewed without issues. Now I would like to generate a cert for the fourth new website. This is what I am getting:

`certbot --apache certonly -w /path/to/docroot/ -d subdomain.example.com`

```
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Plugins selected: Authenticator apache, Installer apache
An unexpected error occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 313, in ssl_wrap_socket
    context.load_verify_locations(ca_certs, ca_cert_dir)
ssl.SSLError: [X509] no certificate or crl found (_ssl.c:3732)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 601, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 346, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 852, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 326, in connect
    ssl_context=context)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 315, in ssl_wrap_socket
    raise SSLError(e)
urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: [X509] no certificate or crl found (_ssl.c:3732)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 440, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 639, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 398, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /directory (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(185090184, '[X509] no certificate or crl found (_ssl.c:3732)'),))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /directory (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(185090184, '[X509] no certificate or crl found (_ssl.c:3732)'),))
Please see the logfiles in /var/log/letsencrypt for more details.
```

This is on an Ubuntu 18.04. I am not sure what is going on.

Answer (score 2):

To mitigate you basically have to un-install the "ca-certificates" as well as "certbot" and do a fresh re-install for them.

Situation:

```
certbot --apache certonly -w /path/to/docroot/ -d subdomain.example.com
```

--> fails :(

Testing:

```
curl -I https://www.gnu.org/
```

--> fails :(

Solution step one:

```
sudo apt remove ca-certificates

sudo apt install ca-certificates
```

Testing:

```
curl -I https://www.gnu.org/
```

--> works :)

Solution step two (Apache users):

```
sudo apt install certbot python3-certbot-apache
```

Solution step two (Nginx users):

```
sudo apt install certbot python3-certbot-nginx
```

Result:

```
certbot --apache certonly -w /path/to/docroot/ -d subdomain.example.com
```

--> works :)

Thanks for this temendous help goes to the Let's Encrypt community! They are awesome!

Comment: This is not working of me. Is there any reason what causes this issue? both CAfile and CApath are existing and readable/accessable. Removing and instaling ca-certificates did not work for me. Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Is it an issue with one of our internal CAs? (we append our own CA to the ca-certificates via `/etc/ca-certificates.conf`

Comment: I have found my issue! Our self signed certificate was provided in DER Format, which curl is not happy with!) just converted it to PEM and everything went smoothly!

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing your experience. I believe you have the same issue for a totally different reason. Anyhow, very good that you found the cause and were able to resolve!

Comment: Just to clarify: I was talking about our Self Signed Company CA certificate which was provided in the wrong format. Actually no other program or tool had any issues with that. Not even the update-ca-certificates command. Hope that helps